# In SOLR DB Is total number of documents always right

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Source collection:
Last Modified:about 2 hours ago
Num Docs:1499744710
Max Doc:1511694401
I use pysolr package and run the folowing: results = solr.search(':', rows=step, start=start) without sort field
It works by SCORE as i understand.
I managed to export  1,073,280,000 documents.
And for the next 1M i got http response 500.
And in solr.log in source SOLR i am getting exception:
o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2147483647
Is it possible, that the actual number of docs is less than i saw in console?

try to export 1499744710 docs in SOLR DB

Comment: Generally you'll want to use cursormarks when exporting documents (and/or the `/export` query endpoint) to avoid Lucene/Solr having to score and sort all the documents at least; I'd start there (and make sure you have a recent version of Solr as well).